# Присвоить v-model из объекта

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuelidate

Подскажите пожалуйста, у меня приходит объект

```
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Склад Москва",
  "description": "Общий склад",
}
```

Использую Vuelidate

```
<input class="form-control" v-model="$v.name.$model">

validations: {
            name: {
                required,
                minLength: minLength(4)
            },
        },
```

Не могу понять как мне присвоить сразу имя из объекта в v-model ?

name должен быть = Склад Москва

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input class="form__input" v-model.trim="name" @input="setName($event.target.value)"/>

  validations: {
    name: {
      required,
      minLength: minLength(4)
    },
  },

  methods: {
    setName(value) {
      this.name = value
      this.$v.name.$touch()
    },
  }
```

Или можно ещё вывести нейм в выч. св-ва с гет/сетером.